# Widget page broken

Tags: widgets

**using WordPress 3.3.1**

Im working on a wordpress site i did not build and i have registered a widget area. There was none before. Now when i go to the widget page it looks like this and i suspect there is something wrong with the WP installation?

The functionality on the widget page does not work properly. For example the content of the widgets in a sidebar are displayed until you minimize the widget. After there is no way to open it again and you have to reload the page to see the content again. The content displays correctly on the front end though.

Problem is still there after having deactivated all plugins.

[image]

Comment: Try to disable plugins one by one and check your widgets page. I am sure that one of your plugins brokes it.

Comment: Is this an old WordPress version in combination with a [reserved widget id](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59985/73)?

Comment: @EugeneManuilov ill try! Im using WordPress 3.3.1.

Comment: @toscho Thanks! I changed the sidebar name to "top_right_banner".

Comment: @toscho & EugeneManuilov: i deactivated all plugins and the same problem persisted. Could it be something in the theme? Its custom made by some unknown developer.